# Sitecore's "Links" button doesn't work because of a null-reference exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am trying to see a certain item's linked items. I am doing this on a client's content management server. When I click on Navigate -> Links, nothing happens. I get this error in the JavaScript console:

> http://sitename.local/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Gallery.Links&…de-DE&vs=1&db=master&sc_content=master&ShowEditor=1&Ribbon.RenderTabs=true
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here's what I see in Sitecore logs:

```
38424 19:09:30 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ownerItem
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field..ctor(ID fieldID, Item ownerItem)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.GetLinkTooltip(Item reference, ItemLink link)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.RenderReferences(StringBuilder result, List`1 references)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

It looks like the `ownerItem` argument is null when creating an item field.

This happens for several different items—e.g. templates and sublayouts.

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: what version of Sitecore do you have?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber as specified in the tags, it's 8.1. To be precise, it's Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 rev. 151207.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was registered as a bug in Sitecore and it was fixed in the Sitecore 8.1 update 2 as a part of the fixes merged from 7.2 update 6:
"Includes all relevant fixes from Sitecore 7.2 update-6"

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Update2/Release%20Notes

"452241: Links dialog fails if cross-database links are present"
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

To fix the issue in Sitecore 8.1 update 1, please install the following patch:

1. Put the attached Sitecore.Support.452241.dll file into the bin folder of your solution.
2. Replace the following string in the     Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Links\Gallery Links.xml dialog:

```xml
     <CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

with the new one:

```xml
     <CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Support.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm,Sitecore.Support.452241"/>
```

Link of the file you can find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l36zqhwjtahl4q2/Sitecore.Support.452241.dll?dl=0

Comment: Typo: this issue is fixed in "8.1 update 2", not "8.2 update"

Comment: Yes you are right. I updated  my answer. I put correct link but the text was wrong